# macOS Sierra Virtual-host not working

Tags: mac, apache-http-server, virtual-host, macos-sierra

About a month ago I updated my Macbook Pro from El capitan to Sierra.

From that moment my mysql and apache wound't work anymore. 
I managed to fix those two (mysql only works now with `sudo mysql.server start`).

But my Vhost still won't work. So far I've managed to work on my projects local trough surfing to: `localhost/projects/projectname`.

Which is an issue sometimes with the paths that are configured inside a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the httpd-vhost.conf and hosts file that are used by apache on Sierra are in an other location than on El Captain. 
So I was using the wrong one.